# How to draw lines between nodes that point at the node center, but stop at the nodes edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm drawing nodes on a circle and switched from drawing lines based on coordinates to drawing them based on named nodes.

The problem now is, that with the following code the lines stop at the edges of the nodes, but don't point at the center.

How do I fix this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \xdef\nodes{16}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nodesminusone}{\nodes-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{log2(\nodes)}
    \xdef\deltadegree{360/\nodes}
    \draw (0,0) circle (6);

    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nodesminusone}
        \node[circle,fill=white,draw=black,thick] (node\i) at (-\i*\deltadegree+90:6) {\i};

    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nodesminusone}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,\N}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{mod(\i+2^\j,\nodes)}
            \draw[->,thick,color=black!10] (node\i) -- (node\result);

        }
    }

    \foreach \i in {2} {
        % predecessor
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{mod(\i-1,\nodes)}
        \draw (node\i) -- (node\result);


        % successor
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{mod(\i+1,\nodes)}
        \draw (node\i) -- (node\result);

        % fingers
        \foreach \j in {0,...,\N}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{mod(\i+2^\j,\nodes)}
        \draw[->,color=blue,thick] (node\i) -- (node\result);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `\pgfmathsetmacro` with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

The reason why this happens is that `\pgfmathsetmacro` returns a floating (or fixed?) point number, not an integer. For example:

```
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\N}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{mod(\i+2^\j,\nodes)}
    \draw[->,color=blue,thick] (node\i) -- (node\result);
    }
```

Here `\result` will be `0.0`, `1.0`, etc. (whatever the result of `mod` is).
However `(node1.0)` means "Node 'node1' at angle 0degr", which draws the arrows to this point. With `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` the `.0` will be truncated and only  `(node1)` etc. is used which gives the wanted result.

Comment: perfect, thanks!  This is hard to debug... any tipps on how I could have found this myself?

Comment: The most difficult thing is to know where to start. But it is always good to look at your intermediate results. You could have looked at the definition of `\result`, i.e. using `\show\result` or better `\edef\A{(node\i) -- (node\result)}\show\A` to see what it passed to the `\draw`.

Comment: Also, minimizing the document to two nodes plus one line might have shown the error more easily. Your code is already to big and complicated to post it like it is anyway.

Comment: @Zoran: You are welcome. Happy TeXing!