# Difference between \newcommand and \pgfmathsetmacro used in TikZ \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes, expansion

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\MA}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\MB}{4};
  \coordinate (V11) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (V44) at (4,4);
  \draw[black] (V11) rectangle (V\MA\MA);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works. However changing the `\draw` command to:

```
   \draw[black] (V11) rectangle (V\MB\MB);
```

produces the following error:

> ! Package pgf Error: No shape named V4 is known
>   .

Why is `\newcommand` working here, when `\pgfmathsetmacro` fails?

Comment: Related Question: [What is the preferred way of defining a TikZ constant?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-defining-a-tikz-constant/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason is that `\pgfmathsetmacro{\MB}{4}` (there is no `;` required) sets `\MB` to the arithmetic result of `4.0` not `4`. Therefore you get `V4.04.0` as node expression. Everything after a dot is taken as node anchor, i.e. TikZ looks for a node `V4` with the anchor `04.0`, which leads to the error you get. (Numeric anchors are also taken as angle (in degrees), so `V\MB` would be node `V4` with the angle node at 0 degrees.)

To fix this use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\MB}{4}` which will give you `4`.

See also the related questions [How to draw lines between nodes that point at the node center, but stop at the nodes edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10289/2975) and [Referring to tikz matrix coordinates using pgf mathematics operations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14601/2975), which where caused from the same behaviour of `\pgfmathsetmacro`.