# Draw n lines in a loop around a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw `\nb` lines from `(0,0)`. All equally spaced.

I keep getting the error "Missing number treated as zero". I have found a lot of similar errors online; these are solved by enclosing the maths in `{}` curly brackets.

I have tried this but it still does not work. Does anybody know what my error is?

```
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \newcommand\ir{2}%Inner radius                                           
        \newcommand\nb{5}%Number of bars                                         
        \newcommand\tta{2*pi/\nb}                                                
                                                                                 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\nb} {                                             
            \newcommand\ctta{{cos(deg(\i*\tta))}}                                
            \newcommand\stta{{sin(deg(\i*\tta))}}                                
            \newcommand\ttta{{tan(deg(\i*\tta))}}                                
                                                                                 
            \newcommand\ltpcx{\ir*\ctta}                                         
            \newcommand\ltpcy{\ir*\stta}                                         
            \draw[] (0,0) -- (\ltpcx,\ltpcy);                                    
        }                                                                        
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
    \caption{General structure of a Data Bank in a MIDAS event.}                 
    \label{fig:BV_structure}                                                     
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calculating the points using `sin` and `cos` how about using the `(<ang>:<rad>)` syntax of Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\ir{2}%Inner radius
  \newcommand\nb{5}%Number of bars
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\nb}
    {
      \draw (0,0) -- ({360*\i/\nb}:\ir);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding the small "T"-parts without any other manual calculations:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\ir{2}%Inner radius
  \newcommand\nb{5}%Number of bars
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\nb}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ang{360*\i/\nb}
      % get the centre point of the line (0,0)--(\ang:\ir) as (tmp)
      \draw (0,0) -- coordinate(tmp) (\ang:\ir)
      % from that centre, draw perpendicular for 0.25 (+(<coord>) syntax)
            (tmp) -- +(\ang + 90:.25);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem in my question was just a MWE. Other than this I need to draw a line perpendicular to each of this lines (centered at the top of the line, and of arbitrary length). It is difficult to explain, it will look like a set of rotating `T's`. That is why I need the coordinates of the points (I think).

Comment: @DanielDuque see the edit. With Ti*k*Z you don't need to calculate much if you don't want to...

Comment: @DanielDuque For future reference, feel free to ask a complete question instead of just a small part and then ask the rest in the answer comments. A sketch of the expected output is also very appreciated to fully understand your needs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to define your variables:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}             
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ir}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nb}{5} 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tta}{2*pi/\nb}      

        \foreach \i in {1,...,\nb} {                                             
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ctta}{cos(deg(\i*\tta))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\stta}{sin(deg(\i*\tta))}  
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ltpcx}{\ir*\ctta} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ltpcy}{\ir*\stta}                                                                          
            \draw (0,0) -- (\ltpcx,\ltpcy);                           
        }                                                                  
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** For your reference, there are a couple of questions and answers that explain quite nicely the difference between `pgfmathsetmacro` and `newcommand` for use as variable in `tikz`:

[Difference between \newcommand and \pgfmathsetmacro used in TikZ \coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94787/118712)

[What is the preferred way of defining a TikZ constant?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47178/118712)

They are not directly related to your question though.

Comment: The result of `\pgfmathsetmacro\<macro>{<number-not-formula>}` is pretty much the same as `\newcommand\<macro>{<number-not-formula>}` except that `\pgfmathsetmacro` takes much longer for this simple task (however for `2*pi/\nb` this is better).

Comment: Meaning your comment applies only to the initial definition of `\ir` and `\nb` in this example?

Comment: Yes, only for `\ir` and `\nb`. But the `\ltpcx` and `\ltpcy` are not really necessary, you could as well just use `\draw (0,0) -- (\ir*\ctta, \ir*\stta);` if those points aren't used elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

A short code with `pstricks` and `multido`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{pst-eucl, multido}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5cm, linewidth=1pt, linecolor=SteelBlue, tbarsize=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3) 
\multido{\I = 0+72}{5}{\psline{-|}(0,0)(3;\I)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\SpecialCoor` is no longer needed. It is already enabled since version x.x.x.x (I forgot).

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay:  I wasn't sure, and didn't have time to check. It  makes the code still shorter. Thanks for the confirmation!