# Tikz foreach draws lines from edge of nodes unexpectedly

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

Consider the following figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    selected/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=yellow!60, very thick},
    unselected/.style={circle, draw=black, very thick}
]
    \node[selected]   (0) at (0, 0) {$x_1$};
    \node[unselected] (1) at (1.5, 0) {$\bar x_1$};
    
    \node[selected]   (2) at (4, 0) {$x_2$};
    \node[unselected] (3) at (5.5, 0) {$\bar x_2$};
    
    \node[unselected] (4) at (8, 0) {$x_3$};
    \node[selected]   (5) at (9.5, 0) {$\bar x_3$};
    
    \node[unselected] (6) at (-1.5, -1.5) {$x_1$};
    \node[selected]   (7) at (-1.5, -3) {$\bar x_2$};
    \node[selected]   (8) at (-1.5, -4.5) {$\bar x_3$};
    
    \node[selected]   (9)  at (0, -6) {$\bar x_1$};
    \node[unselected] (10) at (1.5, -6) {$x_2$};
    \node[selected]   (11) at (3, -6) {$\bar x_3$};
    
    \draw[-] (0) -- (1)
             (2) -- (3)
             (4) -- (5);
             
    \draw[-] (6) -- (7)
             (7) -- (8)
             (6) to [bend right=45] (8);

    \draw[-] (9) -- (10)
             (10) -- (11)
             (9) to [bend right=45] (11);
             
    \draw[-] (6) -- (0)
             (7) -- (3)
             (8) -- (5)
             (9) -- (1)
             (10) -- (2)
             (11) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which looks like: [image: Expected output]

Now, I try using a `foreach` loop and some math:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    selected/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=yellow!60, very thick},
    unselected/.style={circle, draw=black, very thick}
]
    \node[selected]   (0) at (0, 0) {$x_1$};
    \node[unselected] (1) at (1.5, 0) {$\bar x_1$};
    
    \node[selected]   (2) at (4, 0) {$x_2$};
    \node[unselected] (3) at (5.5, 0) {$\bar x_2$};
    
    \node[unselected] (4) at (8, 0) {$x_3$};
    \node[selected]   (5) at (9.5, 0) {$\bar x_3$};
    
    \node[unselected] (6) at (-1.5, -1.5) {$x_1$};
    \node[selected]   (7) at (-1.5, -3) {$\bar x_2$};
    \node[selected]   (8) at (-1.5, -4.5) {$\bar x_3$};
    
    \node[selected]   (9)  at (0, -6) {$\bar x_1$};
    \node[unselected] (10) at (1.5, -6) {$x_2$};
    \node[selected]   (11) at (3, -6) {$\bar x_3$};
    
    \draw[-] (0) -- (1)
             (2) -- (3)
             (4) -- (5);
             
    \foreach \x in {0,...,1}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\a{6+3*\x}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\b{7+3*\x}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\c{8+3*\x}
        \draw[-] (\a) -- (\b)
                 (\b) -- (\c)
                 (\a) to [bend right=45] (\c);
    }
             
    \draw[-] (6) -- (0)
             (7) -- (3)
             (8) -- (5)
             (9) -- (1)
             (10) -- (2)
             (11) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which looks like: [image: Weird output]

Why do the lines in the latter plot all connect to the right-most corner of the nodes rather than how they connected beforehand?

And help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means. -- although I think there's indeed a problem here.

Comment: You should use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro` because otherwise pgf will come up with numbers like `2.0`, where `0` is interpreted as node anchor.

Comment: @ABC thanks, this worked!

Comment: Similar cause: [macros - Difference between \newcommand and \pgfmathsetmacro used in TikZ \coordinate - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94787/difference-between-newcommand-and-pgfmathsetmacro-used-in-tikz-coordinate)

Comment: Looks like same issue as [tikz pgf - How to draw lines between nodes that point at the node center, but stop at the nodes edge - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/how-to-draw-lines-between-nodes-that-point-at-the-node-center-but-stop-at-the-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) (although that one doesn't have images)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: @Roland I don't think it's a good idea to close question because it's solved in comment, because someone may come post a "better" answer (instead, someone could repost the comment in an answer) // although in this case there are duplicates anyway.

Comment: @user202729 Closing questions when they were solved in the comments is common practice here in TeX.SE. There was only a minor problem in the code which was solved by user ABC. He decided to give his answer as a comment, which is also common practice. Repost a comment as an answer of someone else is at least in my opinion inappropriate. It is the author´s choice whereas he posts it as an answer or not. 

Secondly, I cannot close questions. I can only suggest to close them. Other users then have to vote if the closure is justified or not. They can contradict by voting to “leave it open”.

Comment: @user202729 
Finally, you can still leave an answer as a comment or if you think that you have an answer that really helps OP and is too long for a comment you can vote to reopen.

Comment: @Roland ??? only user with some (3k?) rep can vote to reopen. Besides the site isn't really designed to work like that.

Comment: @user202729
3 question marks is always a good way skipping all my arguments.  You could for example ask in the comments that a user with >3k reputation casts a reopen vote if you give a good reason in the comments.
Regardless how it is designed, it is not forbidden, there is no rule against it, it is widely practiced and you can (of course) have a different opinion on that. If you want to complain about how things are handled here and you want to change that, you can start a discussion on Meta.

Comment: @user202729 Besides that, as a said, I do not close questions alone, other people can vote against it. Therefore, it makes absolutely no sense complaining under closure votes (which is an expression of my opinion, which I am also allowed to express). This is also the last thing I am writing to this issue, since we should avoid starting long discussions in comments

Answer (score 0):

Mostly off-topic ...

By use of `matrix` for nodes placement, math function `int` at determining nodes coordinates:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%Tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
fw/.style = {fill=white},
                        ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={circle, draw, semithick, fill=yellow!30,
                    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5em, anchor=west},
             column sep = 1em,
             row sep=1em,
             ]
{ 
            & x_1 & |[fw]| \bar{x}_1 &  & x_2 & |[fw]| x_2 &  & |[fw]| x_3 & \bar{x}_3\\
|[fw]| x_1  &     &                  &  &     &            &  &            &          \\
 \bar{x}_2  &     &                  &  &     &            &  &            &          \\
 \bar{x}_3  &     &                  &  &     &            &  &            &          \\
            & x_1 & |[fw]| x_2 & \bar{x}_3 &  &            &  &            &          \\
};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {2,5,8}
\draw (m-1-\i) -- (m-1-\j);

\draw (m-2-1) -- (m-3-1) -- (m-4-1) to [bend left=45] (m-2-1);

\draw (m-5-2) -- (m-5-3) -- (m-5-4) to [bend left=45] (m-5-2);

\draw (m-1-2) -- (m-2-1)    (m-1-6) -- (m-3-1)  (m-1-9) -- (m-4-1);
\draw (m-1-3) -- (m-5-2)    (m-1-5) -- (m-5-3)  (m-1-9) -- (m-5-4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: using `\foreach` loop image code is not significant shorter ...